# doing POST on Django Rest Framework with viewsets return "405 - METHOD POST NOT ALLOWED"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a HiScore Module for my IOS Apps.

I'm stuck on the POST (probably will have the same issue with the PUT, but not sure) part, I'm getting 405 in Postman.
LIST AND DETAILS are working great, so there is no problem with the models, serialisers or views, just something I'm guessing with adding permissions somewhere

views

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class GameViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = HiScore.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameSerializer

class GameTypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = HiScore.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameTypeSerializer

class GameLevelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = HiScore.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GameLevelSerializer

class HiScoreViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny,]
    queryset = HiScore.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HiScoreSerializer
```

serialisers.py

```
class HiScoreSerializer(ModelSerializer):
image = SerializerMethodField()
class Meta:
    model = HiScore
    fields = ("user", "game", "gameType", "gameLevel", "points", "image")

def get_image(self, obj):
    try:
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=obj.user)
        return profile.image.url
    except:
        return None
```

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(prefix='hiscores', viewset=HiScoreViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing `as_view` in view according to [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/). Try this:

In views:

```
hiscores = HiScoreViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})
```

And in  urls:

```
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    url(r'^hiscores/$', hiscores, name='hiscores')
])
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: But your `HiScoreViewSet` is not the same as the example. You are not using the decorator `@detail_route(methods=['post'])`

Comment: I'm sorry my friend, but i've read the article before asking the question, if you read it you will find the following sentence: The default routers included with REST framework will provide routes for a standard set of create/retrieve/update/destroy style operations, as shown below: so it means that if i do not override any of the CRUD methods i am getting them automatically... and if you go to the browser and write create at the end of url you will see that you are getting a create url... again, it is a permission issue or authentication issue, not a view issue as i understand it.. thanks

Comment: Its definitely not an authentication  issue, else you will should be getting a `401 UNAUTHORIZED`.

Comment: What is the URL you are POSTing to?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/games/hiscores/create/       when i do http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/games/hiscores/1/ I'm getting the details for HiScore 1, if i do http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/games/hiscores/ Im getting all the hi scored, so that is working really great, just the post is not working

Comment: i found this, but can't so I'm guessing the i need to allow POST and thats all:  ---------            If the HTTP method is not configured for use on the server, the server will respond with an HTTP 501 Not Implemented error.

However, when an HTTP method is configured for use on the server, but it has been disabled for a given URI, the server will respond with an HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed error.

Comment: Thanks, that was a huge step forward, still can't do it with postman, but atlas it is working now in the browser, getting post, put, list, details, everything is working on the browser... how to set the json so it won't crash that is a deferent thing i guess but atlas the basics with out permissions and any thing is working.... and the urls have to be += not =... otherwise i loose all the urls for everything