# Django REST framework ModelSetView POST not allowed

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to learn how to use Django REST framework. I want to make a very simple API using ModelViewSet. I've followed the docs but it's not exactly clear to me if ModelViewSet provides an automatic mapping from its `create` to `POST` when doing `router.register(r"polls", QuestionViewSet, basename="polls")`

I keep trying my endpoint:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8005/polls/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "question_text": "how it do",
    "pub_date": "01-01-2021"
}'
```

But it returns: `{"detail":"Method \"POST\" not allowed."}`

Models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Serailizer and ModelViewSet:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ["id", "question_text", "pub_date"]

class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer()
```

Routers:

```
from django.conf.urls import re_path, url, include
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework import routers
from .question import QuestionViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"polls", QuestionViewSet, basename="polls")
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation provided here [DRF ViewSet Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/)

`ModelViewSet` you are using is part of `ViewSet` which provided various methods like `list`, `create` So you need to use it as mentioned below in your `urls.py`

```
question_list = QuestionViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})
```

and your router will use `question_list` you created as below

```
urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns([
    url(r'^polls/$', question_list, name='polls')
])
```

for more details you can also refer [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521149/doing-post-on-django-rest-framework-with-viewsets-return-405-method-post-not)

Comment: I'm trying to set it up without using `question_list = QuestionViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})`. I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work.
After trying to go to the API view in Django Admin (`localhost:8000/api/polls`)
I recieved some errors in my console that told what in my setup was wrong.

First change was this:
I tried to call the `QuestionSerializer` class so I changed it just a reference

```
class QuestionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
```

then I changed my routes to something more simple and easier to read

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("polls", QuestionViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

So I think my main problem was the serializer in this case.
I wouldn't rely on API calls to surface all errors as there can be something wrong internally the API won't touch if the set up is off.